# KStream Aggregation based custom object specific field on a window time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I have a custom object like below.

```
public class CustomObject{  
    public int source;
    public long value;  
    public long timestamp;
}
```

Key and values are like below in Kafka's message.

```
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731364,31300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729572,31400,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731363,31500,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729571,31600,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731362,31700,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729570,31800,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731361,31900,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729569,32000,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731360,32100,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729568,32200,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731359,32300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729567,32400,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731358,32500,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729566,32600,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731357,32700,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729565,32800,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731193,14300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729401,14400,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731192,14500,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729400,14600,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731191,14700,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729399,14800,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731190,14900,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729398,15000,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731189,15100,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729397,15200,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731188,15300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729396,15400,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731187,15500,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729395,15600,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731186,15700,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729394,15800,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.9 Value => -1062731124,28100,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.9 Value => -1062729332,28200,1615979127
```

I need to aggregate the top 3 'source' field events/messages (by total count) for the last 1 mins Window.
After aggregation below reduce messages would be like this from the above list.

**Top 1**

```
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731364,31300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731364,31600,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731364,31900,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731364,32200,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731364,32500,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731364,14300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731364,14600,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731364,15400,1615979127
```

**Top 2**

```
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729572,31400,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729572,32100,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729572,32400,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.9 Value => -1062729572,28100,1615979127
```

**Top 3**

```
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731359,32300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731359,15700,1615979127
```

**Is this requirement is possible to complete through the KStream object?**

```
final KStream<String, CustomObject> source = builder.stream("topic");
source.<???> ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do this with just the DSL. There should be multiple ways to do this.

This is the first that comes to my mind. It may not be the most efficient. You might need to do some mapping/flatMapping to the the source field to be the key. Then you can use `GroupBy` to gather by the source field, then a `TimeWindow` After that a windowed aggregation to get the count for each minute. Then you can remove out the parts of the window that you don't need.

Comment: could you please share some examples.